# Parse XML that has a node with multiple values with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am not quite sure what the XML syntax is that's why I will put two types of XML, please point out the good one.

I have XML that has a node with multiple values:

Case 1:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <image_urls>http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg
    </image_urls>
  </item>
</items>
```

Case 2:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <image_urls>
http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg
    </image_urls>
    <image_urls>http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg
    </image_urls>
  </item>
</items>
```

The struggle I am facing is getting the multiple-valued node with Nokogiri. I tried:

```
item.at("image_urls").to_s.split(" ").inject([]) { |result, element| 
  result << element 
}
```

But this works only in the first variant of the XML. If the correct syntax is the second form, which I believe it is, how can I take both values, as my following implementation only takes the first?

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(self.file.current_path))
xml.xpath("//item").each do |item|
attachments_array = item.at("image_urls").inject([]) { |result, element| 
  result << element
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `css` method, which returns all matches, as opposed to `at` which returns only the first match:

```
text = <<EOD
<items>
  <item>
    <image_urls>http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg
    </image_urls>
  </item>
  <item>
    <image_urls>
http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg</image_urls>
<image_urls>http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg
    </image_urls>
  </item>
</items>
EOD

xml = Nokogiri::XML(text)

xml.css('item').each do |item|
  attachments = item.css('image_urls').map do |url| 
    url.text.strip!.split(' ')
  end.flatten
  p attachments
end
# ["http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"]
# ["http://static.elefant.ro/images/26/95226/husa-belkin-grip-pentru-kindle-3-ebook-reader-albastru_1_categorie.jpg", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"]
```

Comment: and which is the correct way to write that value ? double value inside the tag or double tag?

Comment: @LucianTarna Updated answer.

Comment: No, the first `item` contains 1 `image_urls` tag with 2 links inside. The code processes correctly both of your cases.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You were of great help. Yes I saw after I posted the comment , got ahead of myself, my bad.

Comment: It isn't necessary, or particularly desirable to say "EDIT:" or call out changes to your question or answer. Just incorporate the changes naturally into the document. If we need to see whether something changed we can look as Stack Overflow has version control of all questions and answers.